# Installing gcc 7.4.0 on CentOs 7 does not update my version of libstdc++

Tags: c++, c, centos7

I am using CentOs7 on VirtualBox. I need the 6.0.20 version of libstdc++ at minimum. I installed gcc 7.4.0 on my system from source using the instructions given here: https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-gcc-on-centos-7/

`gcc --version` prints gcc (GCC) 7.4.0 as expected.

Running `strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6|grep GLIBCXX` prints:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
```

According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html, my version of GLIBCXX should be 3.4.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`?

Typically only package installs have `/usr` prefix; the default for anything else is `/usr/local`. I'd check where your GCC was installed because I think you're examining the wrong file. You should find that your one is ultimately a link to a `libstdc++.so.6.0.24`.

`GLIBCXX_3.4.19` implies GCC 4.8.3+ which (from memory) is the CentOS 7-packaged GCC.

Comment: Thank you :) Feeling embarrassed that I spent a whole day on this